# Ошибка при запуске VScode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

При попытке открыть VScode вылетает ошибка:

> The window has crashed(reason:"clean-exit", code 0)

Несколько раз уже переустанавливал, не помогает

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134291

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой финт

1. Правой кнопкой мыши на ярлыке
2. В строке `Target` после кавычек добавьте `-n`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу прощения, у меня на норвежском=(